# Paperclip errors in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

I'm trying to use Paperclip to fill in "image" field at ActiveAdmin Post edit page. Rails 4.0.0, Paperclip 4.2.0. In Post model i've added following code:

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: [ "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png" ] }
```

After submitting form i have following error:

> Paperclip::Error in Admin::PostsController#update
>
> Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'image_file_name'

Looks like I've forgotten to do something. What've i missed to do at this step? Ok, I've manually added

```
attr_accessor :image_file_name
```

After submitting i get another error

> NoMethodError in Admin::PostsController#update
>
> undefined method `image_content_type' for #Post:0x007fb148266e10

I don't know what to do with this one.

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessor :image` in your model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need attr_accessor in your model.
This should be enough.

```
has_attached_file :image
validates_attachment :image, content_type: { content_type: [ "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png" ] }
```

What is still needed are specific columns in database.
Just add migration similar to this and it should be working fine.

```
class AddImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_attachment :posts, :image
  end
end
```

It will add to your model:

```
string   "image_file_name"
string   "image_content_type"
integer  "image_file_size"
datetime "image_updated_at"
```